# Automatically add a combobox when you fill another one

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

Hi i need to make a program where you have to add an undefined number of elements to a list by choosing them from a combobox. I planned to use 4 basic comboboxes and when the user choose an element from the last one, the program should automatically add another one under the last one (i want to use a stackpanel).
How could i do?

Thanks.

My XAML:

```
<StackPanel Name="listPanel" Grid.Column="0" Margin="10">
                        <Label Content="Example" FontWeight="Bold" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                        <ComboBox Name="ex1Combobox" Margin="0,10,0,0"
                                  ItemsSource="{Binding ExList, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                  SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedEx}" 
                                  DisplayMemberPath="Name" 
                                  SelectedValuePath="ID"/>
                        <ComboBox Name="ex2Combobox" Margin="0,10,0,0"
                                  ItemsSource="{Binding ExList, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                  SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedEx}" 
                                  DisplayMemberPath="Name" 
                                  SelectedValuePath="ID"/>
                        <ComboBox Name="ex3Combobox" Margin="0,10,0,0"
                                  ItemsSource="{Binding ExList, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                  SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedEx}" 
                                  DisplayMemberPath="Name" 
                                  SelectedValuePath="ID"/>
                    </StackPanel>
```

Comment: You're looking for an [`ItemsControl`](http://drwpf.com/blog/itemscontrol-a-to-z/). Post your current code and XAML or a screenshot of what you need, or please add more specific information about your current issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a pretty good example of why you should use MVVM.

**Model**

Has a collection of selected values only something like

```
public class MyChoices
{
  public IEnumerable<string> Selections {get; set;}
}
```

**ViewModel**

Has a collection that extends as soon as you modify the last item

```
public class MyChoicesViewModel
{
   public MyChoicesViewModel()
   {
     Selections = new ObservableCollection<ChoiceViewModel>();

     //Add first empty value
     AddNewItem();

     Selections.CollectionChanged += (sender, e) => 
     {
       // If you change the last add another
       if (e.NewItems.Contains(Selections.Last()))
         AddNewItem();

     }; 
   }

   public ObservableCollection<ChoiceViewModel> Selections {get; private set;}

   public void AddNewItem()
   {
     var newItem = new ChoiceViewModel();
     Selections.Add(newItem);
     newItem.PropertyChanged += () => 
      {
        //This is where we update the model from the ViewModel
        Model.Selections = from x in Selections
          select x.Value;
      }
    }
}

public class ChoiceViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   private string _chosen;
   public string Chosen 
   {
     get { return _chosen; }
     set { 
           if (_chosen != value)
           {
             _chose = value;
             OnPropertyChanged();
           }
         }
    }
    public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string property)
    {
      var temp = PropertyChanged;
      if (temp != null)
      {
        temp(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
      }
    }
 }
}
```

View

```
<!-- Then show many of them-->
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Selections}"/>
```

Comment: The code isn't exact as I haven't compiled it, but it should give you the idea to work from. You also might get better mileage using a MVVM library that provides a property change tracking collection, such as ReactiveUI, but that's overkill for this example.